# no new messages for rostopic hz /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw in ros noetic inside docker

Tags: ros, topic, ros-noetic, docker, realsense-camera

steps to reproduce the problem

1. In the first terminal type: `sudo docker run -it --privileged -v /dev:/dev  -v /home/mona:/workspace  -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY --device /dev/bus/usb  ros_noetic`
2. Now, type `hostname -I` to get the IP of master node. `IP`
3. Now, in the same terminal start the master `roslaunch realsense2_camera rs_camera.launch align_depth:=true`
4. In a new terminal type: `sudo docker run -it --privileged -v /dev:/dev  -v /home/mona:/workspace  -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY --device /dev/bus/usb  ros_noetic`
5. Also, in the newly opened terminal, now type: `root@046bedc1feb3:/workspace# ROS_MASTER_URI=http://IP:11311`
6. In the newly opened terminal, you should be able to see list of topics via `rostopic list`
7. Now, pick one of the topics and make sure it has content:  `root@046bedc1feb3:/workspace# rostopic echo /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw`
8. Run this command in the second terminal, and make sure it works. You should see some content posted.

```
    root@046bedc1feb3:/workspace# rosrun roscpp_tutorials babbler
    [ INFO] [1699477519.602225115]: hello world 0
    [ INFO] [1699477519.702355346]: hello world 1
    [ INFO] [1699477519.802340629]: hello world 2
    [ INFO] [1699477519.902507063]: hello world 3
    [ INFO] [1699477520.002284399]: hello world 4
    [ INFO] [1699477520.102295005]: hello world 5
    [ INFO] [1699477520.202313266]: hello world 6
    [ INFO] [1699477520.302315862]: hello world 7
    [ INFO] [1699477520.402323428]: hello world 8
    [ INFO] [1699477520.502385264]: hello world 9
    [ INFO] [1699477520.602336241]: hello world 10
    [ INFO] [1699477520.702384903]: hello world 11
    [ INFO] [1699477520.802342050]: hello world 12
    [ INFO] [1699477520.902314431]: hello world 13
    [ INFO] [1699477521.002317829]: hello world 14
```

also, I see this for the docker ps:

```
(base) mona@ada:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
046bedc1feb3   ros_noetic   "/ros_entrypoint.sh …"   11 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes             frosty_vaughan
93aebfa79986   ros_noetic   "/ros_entrypoint.sh …"   11 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes             amazing_chandrasekhar
```

Problems:

1. No content seen after echo:

`root@046bedc1feb3:/workspace# rostopic echo /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw`

2. No image shown in `rviz`:
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
3. `no new messages` in `rostopic hz topic_name`:

```
    root@046bedc1feb3:/workspace# rostopic hz  /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw
    subscribed to [/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw]
    no new messages
    no new messages
    no new messages
    no new messages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rs_camera.launch` file is opening a **hardware device**, and the Intel-supplied code allows only one linux process at a time **on the machine** to open a particular camera device.

Running the Intel code inside a docker does not let you to escape this limitation.